# How to set a function $key and $value for it

Tags: php, model-view-controller, function

I'm bulding a MVC site and I want to get the number of the page

Let say the url looks like:

> http://site.com/fav/page:6

Where fav is the controller which calls the fav view which in return shows the user favorites.

Now for the page:

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$request    = explode('/', $request);
unset($request[0]); // to remove unwanted values like sitecom

    foreach($request as $i=>$one) {
        if( FALSE!==strpos($one,':')
          && preg_match('/^([a-z0-9\-_]+)\:(.*)$/iu',$one,$m) ) {
            $m[1];
            $m[2];
        }
    }
```

The result is:

```
$m[1] = page;
$m[2] = 6;
```

How to send  `$m[1]` and `$m[2]` to controller. There if `$m[1] = page` to get the `$m[2]` and so on..

Probably with a function, but how ?

Comment: This is nearly unpossible to tell as we don't know anything about your controller interface or how your application is bootstrapped. Can you provide more code?

Answer (score 1):

1. Probably you've to create a router class where logic from the example above will be placed.
2. You have to decide what controller you have to call and pass values from router to this controller, something like this:

---

```
<?php

$router = new Router($_REQUEST);
$ctrlCls = $rounter->getCtrl(); // return your FavController class

$ctlr = new $ctrlCls();
// it'll set an array('page' => N, 'key' => 'value', etc)
$ctrl->setParams($rounter->getParams());
// maybe even $ctrl->setPage($router->getPage());
$ctrl->run();
```